# How to prove that $\dim_k k[V]< \infty$ implies $V$ is a point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $V \subset \Bbb A^n$ be a nonempty variety. How to prove that $\dim_k k[V]< \infty$ implies $V$ is a point.

I am not getting the answer even I do not get what is $\dim_k k[V]$ here?
Because $k[V]$ is an integral domain... So is it the $k$ algebra dimension?

Comment: $k[V]$ is a vector space over $k$.

Comment: Okay so how to use this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that any $k$-algebra (such as $k[V]$) is in particular a $k$-vector space.

So, $k[V]$ is an integral domain which is finite-dimensional over $k$, and $V$ is the set of either maximal ideals or prime ideals of $k[V]$, depending on what framework you're using, but it won't make any difference here. An integral domain finite-dimensional over $k$ is itself a field, finite over $k$. But $k$ is algebraically closed, so we must have $k[V]=k$. Thus the set of maximal (or prime) ideals of $k[V]=k$ is just a single ideal (the zero ideal).